# Can't read models from cloud storage, so the app can't predict images

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-app-engine-python

So I deployed the app that I had made to app engine and it was successful. But for some reason when I tried the /predict API I got an error where the image cannot be predicted. I tried testing the API using postman and the output is like this.
[Postman Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suY9p.png)

Even though I have called the storage bucket that stores the model. This is the code I have made

**app.py**

```
 import os
 import numpy as np
 import tensorflow as tf
 from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
 #from tensorflow import keras
 #from keras.models import load_model
 from PIL import Image
 from flask_cors import CORS
 
 
 app = Flask(__name__)
 CORS(app)
 
 # global variable
 model = None #model
 #db = None

 # download model file from cloud storage 
 def download_model_file():
     from google.cloud import storage
 
     # model bucket details
     BUCKET_NAME = "spezia-bucket"
     PROJECT_ID = "capstone-spezia"
     GCS_MODEL_FILE = "spezia_model.h5"
 
     # initialise a client
     client = storage.Client(PROJECT_ID)
 
     # create a bucket object for our bucket
     bucket = client.bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
 
     # create a blob object from the filepath
     blob = bucket.blob(GCS_MODEL_FILE)
 
     #with blob.open("r") as model:
     #    print(model.read())
 
     folder = '/tmp/'
     if not os.path.exists(folder) :
         os.makedirs(folder)
     # download the file to a destination
     blob.download_to_filename(folder + "model_spezia.h5")
 
 
 #model = load_model('spezia_model.h5')
 
 @app.route('/')
 def main():
     return 'Welcome to Spezia ML Team API for predict many spices'
 
 @app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
 def recognize_image():
     try:
         # deploy model
         global model
         if not model:
             download_model_file()
             model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/tmp/model_spezia.h5')
 
         # open image from request
         img_sample = Image.open(request.files['image'])
         image_path = img_sample
         image_path = image_path.convert('RGB')
         image_path.close()
 
         # prepare image for prediction
         img = np.array(img_sample.resize((150,150)))
         
         x = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
         images = np.vstack([x])
         image_path.close()
 
 
         # predict
          prediction_array = model.predict(images)
 
          class_names =  ['asam jawa', 'cengkeh', 'daun jeruk', 'daun salam', 
                         'jahe', 'kayu manis', 'keluak', 'kemiri', 'ketumbar', 
                         'kunyit', 'lada hitam', 'pekak','serai']
         result = {
             'prediction': class_names[np.argmax(prediction_array)],
             'confidence': '{:2.0f}%'.format(100 * np.max(prediction_array))
         }
 
         return jsonify(isError=False, message='Success', statusCode=200, data=result), 200
 
      except Exception as e:
         print(str(e))
         return jsonify(message='Something went wrong'), 500
 
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(debug=True, port=8080)
```

**requirement.txt**

```
 Flask==2.2.2
 Flask-Cors==3.0.10
 tensorflow==2.11.0
 keras==2.11.0
 numpy==1.23.5
 Pillow==9.3.0
 google-cloud-storage==2.7.0
```

Thanks for help and sorry for my bad English

Comment: Check the logs. What does the log say? Also, since you've deployed to GAE, it will automatically pick the project Id and you can (should) just do ```client = storage.Client()```

Comment: I don't really understand, but in logMessage: "This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application." And I set severity have debug

Comment: That usually means that your App has run out of resources e.g. your App has run out of memory i.e. it requires more memory than is available for your instance. Your logs might be able to tell you how much memory you've used. If it doesn't, you can try running your App locally & figure out the memory being used. You can also figure out the size of the model you're downloading (it is being read into the App's memory) & estimate the amount of memory your App is using and then look at the instance classes here - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard to find out which one you should use